# Unable to find Blockly Generator function in Angular application

Tags: blockly, google-blockly

I am trying to build a Blockly Application using Angular. I installed Blockly using npm . I also added the following scripts in angular.json

```
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/blockly/blockly_compressed.js",
              "node_modules/blockly/blocks_compressed.js",
              "node_modules/blockly/python_compressed.js",
              "node_modules/blockly/msg/en.js"
            ]
```

Though i can use `import * as Blockly from 'blockly'` to import blockly in the application and use other functions, I am not able to find Generator functions like `Blockly.Python['text_indexOf']`

I am using **blockly: ^3.20200625.2** and **@angular/cli: ~9.1.0** versions.

Am i missing something. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with electron+angular app building, the next solution had helped me.

Blockly's reference [says](https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/configure/web/code-generators) that Python's generator class should be included with file `python_compressed.js` right after `blockly_compressed.js`. So I need to include these files.

First I've used [copy-webpack-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/) to copy needed files from Blockly's install directory `node_modules/blockly` to `assets/js`:

```
var CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: [
        ...
            new CopyPlugin([
                {
                    from: 'node_modules/blockly/blockly_compressed.js',
                    to: 'assets/js/[name].[ext]'
                },
                {
                    from: 'node_modules/blockly/blocks_compressed.js',
                    to: 'assets/js/[name].[ext]'
                },
                {
                    from: 'node_modules/blockly/python_compressed.js',
                    to: 'assets/js/[name].[ext]'
                },
                {
                    from: 'node_modules/blockly/msg/en.js',
                    to: 'assets/js/msg/[name].[ext]'
                },
            ]),
        ...
    ]
    ...
}
```

After I've added scripts calling from `js/assets` directly from `index.html`'s bottom:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body><app-root>...</app-root></body>
    <script src="assets/js/blockly_compressed.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/blocks_compressed.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/python_compressed.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/msg/en.js"></script>
</html>
```

After webpack build check python's generator in console:

```
> typeof Blockly.Python
< "object"
```